# How to invoke the child member function inside the parent class member function without using the object

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, googletest, googlemock

How to call the member function of child inside the member function of parent class
This needs to accomplished as a part of gtest and gmock.

Example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void my_read()
   {
      cout << "Base read\n";
   }
    void my_write()
   {
      cout << "Base write\n";
       my_read();
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    void my_read()
    {
        cout << "Derived read\n";
     }
};
int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.my_write();
   return 0;
 }
```

The desired output is:

```
   Base write
   Derived read
```

The actual output is:

```
   Base write
   Base read
```

As this is the situation of writing the test case, I cant change the code implementaion.
Considering Derived class as a Mock class from the Base, I have specific implementation for my_read().
How to use this implementation in child without passing any other instances.

Comment: If you can't change any implementation of base, then `Base::my_write` would always call `Base::my_read` becaseu setting `Base::my_write` to `virtual` isn't allowed. Non-mockable object is non-mockable..

Comment: @LouisGo is correct. The compiler might even have inlined `Base::my_write`, so there's no call left that you can mock. You **must** change the source and recompile to insert that virtual call, so there's a point where mocking is possible.

Comment: This should be self-evident: Without changing `Base`, you cannot change `Base`. As it stands the implementation of `my_write` does not allow code injection -- apart from nasty pre-processor tricks.

Comment: The only way I can come up with is to modified the compiler to make all class methods to be virtual, this is not very difficult in clang, check http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Adding-nodes-to-Clang-s-AST-td4054800.html

Answer (score 0):

Just one solution's seen by me yet, declaring the `my_read()` with `virtual` (which modifies the base a bit):

```
virtual void my_read()
{
  std::cout << "Base read\n";
}
```

Solves your problem. The output was:

```
Base write
Derived read
```

Comment: OP says they cannot change `Base`.

Comment: @bitmask This is the only way I've seen so far yet. I've added about the change in parenthesis though.